# A cube structure from image, and rotation

Tags: swift, animation, 3d

After long time with iOS, I never had 3D experience, and now I need to create 1 cube that can be rotated.

I am trying to figure out how to create a cube from an image , and rotate it in swift.

This link https://www.raywenderlich.com/12667/how-to-rotate-a-3d-object-using-touches-with-opengl has made exactly that but its not swift.

His other tutorials for swift are much more complex.

I am looking to have 2 functions :

1. create a 3d cube from image
2. rotate it to a certain x,y,z

Is there a simple Apple 3D animation class to that ?

Comment: "from image"? As in...

Comment: @tktsubota as  one of its sides. Exactly like done in the link.

Comment: Have you tried SceneKit?

Comment: @Curnelious Have you create a 3d cube from Image?  I want to Do the same, Please Help!

Answer (score 0):

```
import UIKit
import SceneKit   
import QuartzCore

class ViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let scene = SCNScene()
    let scnView = self.view as! SCNView
    scnView.scene = scene

    let cameraNode = SCNNode()
    cameraNode.camera = SCNCamera()
    scene.rootNode.addChildNode(cameraNode)
    cameraNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 0, z: 15)   //where will be situated a cube

    scnView.allowsCameraControl = true       //that's for you can spin it any direction with your finger if you are bored
    scnView.autoenablesDefaultLighting = true   //Lightting 

    var geometries = [
        SCNBox(width: 4.0, height: 4.0, length: 4.0, chamferRadius: 0),
    ] //This is the cube with parameters of 4

    var materials = [SCNMaterial]()
    for i in 1...6 {
        let material = SCNMaterial()
        if i == 1 { material.diffuse.contents = UIImage (named: "qr.png") }
        if i == 2 { material.diffuse.contents = UIColor(red: 0.6784, green: 0.698, blue: 0.7412, alpha: 1.0) }
        if i == 3 { material.diffuse.contents = UIColor(red: 0.6784, green: 0.698, blue: 0.7412, alpha: 1.0) }
        if i == 4 { material.diffuse.contents = UIColor(red: 0.6784, green: 0.698, blue: 0.7412, alpha: 1.0) }
        if i == 5 { material.diffuse.contents = UIColor(red: 0.6784, green: 0.698, blue: 0.7412, alpha: 1.0) }
        if i == 6 { material.diffuse.contents = UIColor(red: 0.7882, green: 0.7961, blue: 0.8863, alpha: 1.0) }
        materials.append(material)
    } //this is to coloring each side of cube

    for i in 0..<geometries.count {
        let geometry = geometries[i]
        let node = SCNNode(geometry: geometry)

        node.geometry?.materials = materials
        node.runAction(SCNAction.repeatForever(SCNAction.rotateBy(x: 1, y: 1, z: 1, duration: 5)))
        scene.rootNode.addChildNode(node)
    }
 }
```

Comment: Please put a description and elaborate why your answer will work.